# How to send the output of `time some_command` run repeatedly to a file?

Tags: command-line

If I run `time uname -a | awk '{ print substr($3,1,9)" "$12 }'`, I get:

```
$ time uname -a | awk '{ print substr($3,1,9)" "$12 }'
4.15.0-70 x86_64

real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.016s
$
```

I would like to run the above command several times and save the entire output to a file. So I tried

```
for i in {1..10}; do time uname -a | \
awk '{ print substr($3,1,9)" "$12 }' >> uname.txt; done
```

But only `4.15.0-70 x86_64` is sent ten times to the file `uname.txt`. The output of `time` is sent to the screen for each run and not to `uname.txt`.

So how can I have the output of `time` also captured in `uname.txt`?

---

I can use `script` and that works but the output isn't pretty:

```
(B[m(B[m(B[m4.15.0-70 x86_64

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.013s
sys 0m0.007s
(B[m(B[m(B[m4.15.0-70 x86_64

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.009s
(B[m(B[m(B[m4.15.0-70 x86_64

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Or as an image:

[image: Part of script output as seen in Geany]

I know I could clean it up if there's no better way.

Comment: problem is `time` command; even alone, you won't get lines expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```bsh
for i in {1..10}; do 
  { time uname -a | awk '{ print substr($3,1,9)" "$12 }'; } &>> uname.txt
done
```

Output:

```
4.15.0-54 i686

real    0m0,009s
user    0m0,007s
sys 0m0,000s
4.15.0-54 i686

real    0m0,016s
user    0m0,005s
sys 0m0,004s
4.15.0-54 i686

...
```

Comment: What's the value of using a variable here? why not simply `do { time uname -a | awk '{ print substr($3,1,9)" "$12 }'; } >> uname.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @steeldriver updated the answer with your recommendation.

Comment: Check whether you need just `>>` or `&>>` as used by steeldriver.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica ah yes I always forget about the bash `&>>` redirector